# How to use "func:padStr for adding leading spaces

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement in which I need to achieve below logic:

We need to add leading spaces in prefix, and make sure that it is always be 6.
We need to add leading spaces in base, and make sure that it is always be 8.
We need to add trailing spaces in suffix, and make sure that it is always be 8.

I have used pad string, but only able to achieve addition of trailing spaces.
Please help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:func="myfunc" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
<xsl:function name="func:padStr">
    <xsl:param name="str"/> 
    <xsl:param name="chr"/> 
    <xsl:param name="len"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="pad">
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $len">
            <xsl:value-of select="$chr" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($str,$pad),1,$len)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:param name="break" select="'&#13;&#10;'" />



    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="Prefix" select="A/W1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Base" select="A/W2"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Suffix" select="A/W3"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="func:padStr($Prefix,' ',6)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="func:padStr($Base,' ',8)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="func:padStr($Suffix,' ',8)"/>
                </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
      <A>
    <W1>9876</W1>
   <W2>gt465</W2>
  <W3>fr</W3>
    </A>
```

Expected Output:

'  9876   gt465fr      '

In this prefix is 4 then 2 spaces, base 5 so 3 spaces, suffix is 2 then add 6 spaces..it may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current function only does right padding, so you need a new function to do left padding

```
<xsl:function name="func:padStrLeft">
    <xsl:param name="str"/> 
    <xsl:param name="chr"/> 
    <xsl:param name="len"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="pad">
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $len">
            <xsl:value-of select="$chr" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($pad, $str), string-length($str) + 1)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Alternatively, to do it in one function, add a new parameter to indicate if you want right-padding or not

```
<xsl:function name="func:padStr">
    <xsl:param name="str"/> 
    <xsl:param name="chr"/> 
    <xsl:param name="len"/> 
    <xsl:param name="rightpad" />
    <xsl:variable name="pad">
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $len">
            <xsl:value-of select="$chr" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="if ($rightpad) 
                          then substring(concat($str,$pad),1,$len) 
                          else substring(concat($pad, $str), string-length($str) + 1)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Then call it like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="func:padStr($Prefix,' ',6,false())"/>
<xsl:value-of select="func:padStr($Base,' ',8,false())"/>
<xsl:value-of select="func:padStr($Suffix,' ',8,true())"/>
```